# Meteor signaling without db write

Tags: meteor

I've been looking for a good way to do, but haven't found anything that doesn't seem hacky.  I want to signal the client without going through the database and a subscription. For example, in a game I want to send a message to the client to display "Player 1 almost scores!". I don't care about this information in the long run, so I don't want to push it to the DB. I guess I could just set up another socket.io, but I'd rather not have to manage a second connection if there is a good way to go it within meteor. Thanks!  (BTW, have looked at [Meteor Streams](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-streams), but it appears to have gone inactive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that Meteor provides real-time communication from the server to clients through [Publish and Subscribe](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html) mechanism, which is typically used to send your MongoDB data and later modifications.

You would like a similar push system but without having to record some data into your MongoDB.

It is totally possible re-using the Meteor Pub/Sub system but without the database part: while with [`Meteor.publish`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-publish) you typically return a Collection Cursor, hence data from your DB, you can also use its low-level API to send arbitrary real-time information:

> Alternatively, a publish function can directly control its published record set by calling the functions [`added`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#publish_added) (to add a new document to the published record set), [`changed`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#publish_changed) (to change or clear some fields on a document already in the published record set), and [`removed`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#publish_removed) (to remove documents from the published record set). […]

Simply do not return anything, use the above mentioned methods and do not forget calling `this.ready()` by the end of your publish function.

See also the Guide about [Custom publications](https://guide.meteor.com/data-loading.html#custom-publication)

```js
// SERVER
const customCollectionName = 'collection-name';
let sender; // <== we will keep a reference to the publisher

Meteor.publish('custom-publication', function() {
  sender = this;

  this.ready();

  this.onStop(() => {
    // Called when a Client stops its Subscription
  });
});

// Later on…
// ==> Send a "new document" as a new signal message
sender.added(customCollectionName, 'someId', {
  // "new document"
  field: 'values2'
});

// CLIENT
const signalsCollectionName = 'collection-name'; // Must match what is used in Server
const Signals = new Mongo.Collection(signalsCollectionName);
Meteor.subscribe('custom-publication'); // As usual, must match what is used in Server

// Then use the Collection low-level API
// to listen to changes and act accordingly
// https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observe
const allSignalsCursor = Signals.find();
allSignalsCursor.observe({
  added: (newDocument) => {
    // Do your stuff with the received document.
  }
});
```

Then how and when you use `sender.added()` is totally up to you.

Note: keep in mind that it will send data individually to a Client (each Client has their own Server session)

If you want to *broadcast* messages to several Clients simultaneously, then the easiest way is to use your MongoDB as the glue between your Server sessions. If you do not care about actual persistence, then simply re-use the same document over and over and listen to *changes* instead of additions in your Client Collection Cursor observer.

Comment: Thanks,  that’s what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

It's completly fine to use the database for such a task.
Maybe create a collection of "Streams" where you store the intended receiver and the message, the client subscribe to his stream and watches any changes on it.
You can then delete the stream from the database after the client is done with it.
This is a lot easier than reinventing the wheel and writing everything from scratch.